# How to remove the index.html path from url in golang

Tags: http, url, go

How do I remove the `index.html` from my URL bar e.g. `localhost:8000/index.html`

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", new(MyHandler))

    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
type MyHandler struct {
    http.Handler
}

func (this *MyHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    path := "public" + req.URL.Path
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(string(path))

    if err == nil {
        w.Write(data)
    } else {
        w.WriteHeader(404)
        w.Write([]byte("404 - " + http.StatusText(404)))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a condition to serve index.html if the URL path is empty:

```
path := "public"
if req.URL.Path == "/" {
    path += "/index.html"
} else {
    path += req.URL.Path
}
```

Also, it would be a good idea to use [`net/http.ServeFile`](https://godoc.org/net/http#ServeFile) over manually writing the data to the output stream (see [`net/http#ServeContent`](https://godoc.org/net/http#ServeContent)'s documentation to learn why this is a good idea).

It's also worth noting that a [built-in handler for serving files](https://godoc.org/net/http#FileServer) exists.

Comment: Thanks Tim totally just learning this by watching http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/creating-web-applications-go  These are just questions popping up that I cannot seem to find simple answer to on stack! thanks again!